# A node that's a subscriber, a publisher and uses dynamic parameters [Python]

Tags: ros, python, publisher, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I have defined two custom dynamic parameters, gain1 and gain2, in a cfg file. I would like to use these in a node that subscribes and publishes to two topics. Here's what i tried:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from dynamic_reconfigure.server import Server
from myPack.cfg import paramConfig

def param_callback(config, level):
      gain1 = config.gain1
      gain2 = config.gain2
      return config

def callback1(msg):
      in1 = msg.data

def callback2(msg):
      in2 = msg.data

rospy.init_node('mixer')
srv = Server(paramConfig, param_callback)

sub1 = rospy.Subscriber('in1', Float64, callback1)
sub2 = rospy.Subscriber('in2', Float64, callback2)

pub1 = rospy.Publisher('out1', Float64)
pub2 = rospy.Publisher('out2', Float64)

out1 = Float64()
out2 = Float64()

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      out1.data = in1*gain1
      out2.data = in2*gain2
     
      pub1.publish(out1)
      pub2.publish(out2)
```

But it seems the subscribers callbacks don't work. This error is given for the first line of the while loop.

```
 NameError: name 'in1' is not defined
```

Note that the subscription and parameter server code work fine individually.

Am I using the right method?

**Update:**
As suggested by gvdhoorn, I had to define  `gain1` and `gain2` as global variables **and** initialize `in1` and `in2` before the while loop. The latter because the program could reach the while loop before a callback. In this case, `in1` is still undefined and I would receive the same error .

I feel this method is a bit inelegant and as gvdhoorn pointed out, using a class instead of global variables is better programming.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278409/a-node-that%27s-a-subscriber,-a-publisher-and-uses-dynamic-parameters-%5Bpython%5D/) by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2017-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2018-01-08**:
Another problem you should change: your publishers are being declared as Subscribers.
`pub1 = rospy.Subscriber('out1', Float64)`
Change to :
`pub1 = rospy.Publisher('out1', Float64, queue_size=1)`

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-08**:
Whoops. Just saw that. The node is a simplified version of what I use and written specifically for this question so I never actually ran it.

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2018-01-08**:
Ah ok then! It's just that I reproduced your problem, fixed the variable scope and got into another problem related to that (A `Subscriber` object doesn't have the `.publish` method). =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But it seems the subscribers callbacks don't work.

The callbacks are probably fine, and this is not a ROS problem (so there's nothing wrong with the publishers, subscribers or dyn re_cfg here), but most likely a Python scoping problem: you're trying to use variables (`in1`, `in2`, `gain1` and `gain2`) in the body of your `while`-loop that are out of scope at that point (ie: they do not 'exist' there). See [random tutorial about Python variable scopes](https://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) for some explanation.

A quick work-around could be to put `in1`, `in2`, `gain1` and `gain2` in the *global* scope. Using a class and making those variables *members* would probably be nicer.

---

Edit: note that besides the scoping issue your current implementation also has some other issues:

1. no rate limiting of your main `while-loop` (see [wiki/rospy/Overview/Time - Sleeping and Rates](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates))
2. mixing an event system with a periodic, synchronous sampling one (and assuming that the event callbacks will be serviced at suitable intervals so the `pub1` and `pub2` publishers don't republish old data)

The first can lead to starvation of other tasks/nodes, while the second can lead to missed updates and publishing stale data (among other things).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2017-12-30**:
Thank you. Is there a way to fix the second issue? I haven't found a different way to implement a publisher /subscriber that uses dynamic parameters.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-30**:
I'm not sure I understand how the dynamic reconfigure complicates things. Can you elaborate?

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2017-12-30**:
I think it is a misunderstanding on my part. By "an event system", I thought you meant the parameter server.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-30**:
No. ROS pub-sub is event-based, not just dynamic reconfigure.

Your `while`-loop implements a sync, periodic sampling on top of that. I just wanted to point that out.